# In C#, is it possible to determine the type parameter of a generic at runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Here's sort of what I have (using Rhino Mocks, but that isn't central to the question):

```
var entityMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IEntity>();
this.Cache = MockRepository.GenerateStub<Cache<IEntity>>();
```

Is it possible to be more specific in setting the type parameter of `Cache<T>`? Something like:

```
var entityMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IEntity>();
this.Cache = MockRepository.GenerateStub<Cache<typeof(entityMock)>>();
```

This doesn't compile of course. But I would like to, if possible, use the type that Rhino Mocks generates, which is a concrete implementation of `IEntity`.

Comment: Peter, please reconsider the accepted answer; Adams answer is now more complete and to the point.

Comment: Wow, these answers have been more powerful than I expected. A little over my head! I will reconsider the answer, Lucero, but you'll have to give me some time to experiment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>Note that although RhinoMocks is mentioned, the ***only*** specific part is `GenerateStub` which creates a concrete implementation around the provided type; the rest is agnostic of RhinoMocks.</sub>

Generic type arguments are resolved at compile time - as you know; this disallows entering the type as a generic argument in-line without reflection (ie: `var list = new List<typeof(int)>();`).

However, you **can** create generic types using reflection. In essense, if you can get the type of the dynamic proxy from something like:

```
var entityMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IEntity>();
var dynamicType = entityMock.GetType();
```

`MockRepository` has a `GenerateStub` that takes a `Type` and `object[]` arguments, so carrying on from above:

```
var cacheType = typeof(Cache<>);
var genericType = cacheType.MakeGenericType(dynamicType);
var stubbed = MockRepository.GenerateStub(genericType, null);
```

The `stubbed` item is unfortunately of type `object`, but as Lucero states in the comments, it would be possible to use generic co-variance to gain a type more usable than just `object`. I demonstrate this below.

---

Based on an interesting discussion with Lucero, if you define a new `ICache<out T>` interface to represent the Cache, the generic co-variance will then allow you to cast the resulting proxies to the base type (of `ICache<IEntity>`):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // The concrete entity.
        IEntity entityMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IEntity>();
        entityMock.Stub(s => s.Name).Return("Adam");

        // The runtime type of the entity, this'll be typeof(a RhinoMocks proxy).
        Type dynamicType = entityMock.GetType();

        // Our open generic type.
        Type cacheType = typeof(ICache<>);

        // Get the generic type of ICache<DynamicProxyForIEntity> (our closed generic type).
        Type  genericType = cacheType.MakeGenericType(dynamicType);

        // Concrete instance of ICache<DynamicProxyForIEntity>.
        object stubbed = MockRepository.GenerateStub(genericType, null);

        // Because of the generic co-variance in ICache<out T>, we can cast our
        // dynamic concrete implementation down to a base representation
        // (hint: try removing <out T> for <T> and it will compile, but not run).
        ICache<IEntity> typedStub = (ICache<IEntity>)stubbed;

        // Stub our interface with our concrete entity.
        typedStub.Stub(s => s.Item).Return(entityMock);

        Console.WriteLine(typedStub.Item.Name); // Prints "Adam".
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public interface ICache<out T>
{
    T Item { get; }
}

public interface IEntity
{
    string Name { get; }
}
```

Comment: This is not correct. You can certainly create closed generic types at runtime with type arguments decided on the spot.

Comment: @Jon Never mind, I just connected the two, as you say all you need is the `Type`, which will be easily available at runtime in any case. Wasn't thinking straight apparently :-)

Comment: Downvote is mine. Combine the code of Jon and interfaces that use generic convariance (like IEnumerable<> does) and you gain the ability to use more specific implementations than declared at runtime (e.g. you have a variable of type IEnumerable<object> and you create a List<Foo> through reflection with MakeGenericType and the Activator, then you can assign that to this variable without reverting to object or dynamic). Therefore it's just wrong to say that you can neve do this.

Comment: @Lucero I don't say you can never do this... well, if you take the first "no" as "never" then I suppose it can be interpreted such. I'll clear that up. But that first "no" was to the point of declaring generic types in-line with the definition, which as we all know, isn't possible.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth, quote: "... you'd *never* be able to cast this to a strong type in code ...". A generic covariant interface qualifies as strong type nevertheless, no?

Comment: @Lucero You'd never be able to cast it to a strong type of the dynamic proxy created by RhinoMocks. Variance doesn't give you the type directly. But again, I'll clear this up.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth, that may be true if RhineMocks doesn't provide a covariant interface for its mocks. However, the OP explicitly stated: "using Rhino Mocks, but that isn't central to the question", so that pointing to cases where this is indeed possible is better than saying no, never...

Comment: @Lucero No, but the idea that the type is dynamically created at runtime *is* central to the question and will fall into the same boat as RhinoMocks dynamic types. I don't know RhinoMocks well enough specifically to say what you can and can't do with it, I just know you won't be able to write: `RhinoMocks.StubbedIEntity val = (RhinoMocks.StubbedIEntity)entityStub;`, which is what I was getting at.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13723/discussion-between-adam-houldsworth-and-lucero)

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth, as far as I can tell, in this specific case it's pretty much under the control of the OP to actually use a generic covariant interface ICache<out T>, and then declare the Cache property as ICache<IEntity>; you can then create the type as discussed and assign it to the property no problem.

Comment: @Lucero I've updated my answer with this idea of yours, hopefully it's in the right ball park. The end result is the `ICache` is implemented against the dynamic proxy for `IEntity`.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth, yes that's exactly what I had in mind. Good job!

Answer (score 3):

You *can* create a closed generic type at runtime using reflection. The problem is that you will most likely have to *continue* operating it using just reflection because (given that its type is not known at compile time) you cannot type it as something usable directly.

For example, to create a list of "something":

```
public IList CreateList(Type t)
{
    var openListType = typeof(List<>);
    return (IList)openListType.MakeGenericType(t);
}
```

This example illustrates a couple of important points:

1. You cannot do this if the "target type" is specified at compilation. In other words, `CreateList` cannot accept `t` as a generic type parameter and still allow the same functionality.
2. In the worst case scenario the new instance cannot be typed as anything else than `object`. Here we know that we will always create an `IList`, so things are a bit better.

I don't have experience with Rhino Mocks, but in your case it would translate to this:

```
var entityMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IEntity>()
var cacheType = typeof(Cache<>).MakeGenericType(entityMock.GetType());
this.Cache = MockRepository.GenerateStub(cacheType);
```

...but **only if** an appropriate `GenerateStub` overload is available.

Answer (score 0):

If code will wish to perform different actions based whether or not a generic type meets certain constraints, especially if some of these actions can't even compile if the generic type doesn't, it may be helpful to use a pattern somewhat similar to the that used by classes like `Comparer<T>` and `EqualityComparer<T>`.  The trick is to use a static class with a generic parameter `T` which holds a static delegate to a method which has a parameter of type `T`, and have static methods, each of which takes a possibly-constrained generic parameter of type `U` and has a signature that will be compatible with the aforementioned delegate when `U` matches `T`.  The first time an attempt is made to use the static class or its delegate, the static constructor of the generic class can use Reflection to construct a delegate to the method which should be used for the type.  Such a call will fail at run-time if one attempts to construct a delegate to a generic method in such fashion as to violate the generic constraints of thereof; since exceptioins in static constructors are very bad, one should make sure to construct one's delegates using valid functions.  On the other hand, once the delegate has been constructed once, all future calls can be dispatched straight through that delegate, with no need for further Reflection or type checking.